# Bigquery - How to use a previously created column from aggregation?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to recreate a query from Teradata on bigquery, query is very simple as I am just trying to get familiar.
This works perfectly in Teradata however in bigquery it is not recognizing the expression TY_SALES1 OR LY_SALES1. I tried using "" ,'', `` and none worked.

Is there any solution or I will always have to create the formula using them SUM(TY_SALES)/SUM(LY_SALES) ??
THANKS

```
SUM(TY_SALES) AS TY_SALES1,
SUM(LY_SALES) AS LY_SALES1,
TY_SALES1/LY__SALES1
FROM 
MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

options are

```
SELECT
  SUM(TY_SALES) AS TY_SALES1,
  SUM(LY_SALES) AS LY_SALES1,
  SUM(TY_SALES)/SUM(LY_SALES)
FROM 
MYTABLE
```

or

```
SELECT
  TY_SALES1,
  LY_SALES1,
  TY_SALES1/LY_SALES1
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(TY_SALES) AS TY_SALES1,
    SUM(LY_SALES) AS LY_SALES1
  FROM 
  MYTABLE
)
```